# Magento: Promotions - Payment Method

Tags: payment, promotions

We want to offer promotion (e.g. $10 off) as long as customer uses a specific payment type (e.g. COD).

I can easily set up the rule for the $10 off in the “Shopping Cart Price Rule” and select “Payment Type” under “Cart Attribute” for the “Condition”. But get error when entering “Promotion Code” on the Cart page.  If I remove the “Payment Type” condition then the “Promotion Code” works.

Even though “Payment Type” is available for Shopping Cart Price Rules, is this functionality working?

Comment: The answer to "is this functionality working" when it comes to Magento is almost universally "probably not." You can't know for sure without looking at the code.

Comment: did you found solution ? what to do to create coupon code based on payment methods ?

Comment: Check the payment method code and check the condition in the admin panel properly. Also check for the other payment methods either its working or not.

Comment: @AsheemPatro seems this is default magento issue...... when you get free time, please check once....

Answer (score 5):

For payment-type rules it's preferred to not use a coupon code, as the coupon will not be able to be activated unless you've first entered payment details, then returned to the cart to enter the coupon, **then** return to checkout to complete.

Rather set this up as an automatic pricing rule. If you want this rule to not be able to be combined with other rules, set 'Stop other rules from applying' on the rule, then set it with a lower priority.

Comment: Make sure you tailor your messaging on the cart what the benefit of using COD is -- usually this is more of a marketing solution than a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement this in default Magento 1.9.2 with the above condition you have explained in your question. I am able to get 10% discount at the checkout if the payment method is "Cash On Delivery".

Check all the attached screenshots for your detailed understanding and the admin settings. If you are facing any issue please get back to me.

[image][image]
[image]
[image]
[image]